# Residue of a a complex quotient

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have the following Laurent expansion corresponding to the function:
$$f(z)=\frac{z+2}{z^2-4iz-3}$$
$$f(z)=\left(-1+\frac{1}{2}i\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{i}{z}\right)^n+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}i\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{3i}\right)^n$$

The residue of $f(z)$ at $3i$ is: $Res(f;3i)=\frac{3}{2}-i$. Where can I see it in the Laurent expansion written above?

Comment: You have to do the Laurent series around $3i$, this means that you have to represent the function as powers of $z-3i$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rather than the Laurent expansion at $z=0$, use partial fractions:
$$
\frac{z+2}{z^2-4iz-3}=\frac{\frac32-i}{z-3i}+\frac{-\frac12+i}{z-i}
$$

**Comment:** Note that your Laurent expansion diverges at $z=3i$, so it is going to be very difficult to draw any conclusion about the behavior of $f(z)$ at $z=3i$ from it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see it use use to expand $f$ as a Laurent series around $3i$, i.e.,
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_k(z-3i)^k,
$$
and your question is related to the coefficient $a_{-1}$.

Comment: I am trying to do so but I really don't know how. I use the formula for the geometric series to expand the Laurent series, but I don't know how to apply it in the case of expanding it over $3i$.